# why is the time function in time module diplaying milliseconds greater than 1000 when it can convert it to seconds?

Tags: python

I'm currently learning Python and as I was trying time module I got a little confused.

```
import time
time.time()
1556477137.7941282
```

Since the number after the decimal represents milliseconds, I was expecting a number less than 1000 because 1000milliseconds = 1 seconds.
1556477137(represents seconds) and 7941282(represents milliseconds)
Why isn't this "7941282" converted to seconds?

Comment: The number returned is a floating point number. Why would you think the digits after the decimal point would be milliseconds?

Comment: That's not how decimal places work. 7 is the number of tenths of a second, 9 the number of hundredths, 4 the number of thousandths (milliseconds) and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The number after the decimal point is not the number of milliseconds. If you have 13.123456 seconds, you have 13 seconds and `0.123456 seconds = 123.456 milliseconds`.
If you're living in the EU you are probably used to seeing a , instead of .

Comment: 123.456 milliseconds; there can't be more than 1000 milliseconds, or it *would* tick a second!

Comment: I knew I would mess it up ;)

Comment: The book I'm using  says I have 13 seconds as you said but 123456 milliseconds. The book's title is Introduction to programming using python by Y.Daniel.Liang

Comment: Perhaps your book only shows numbers with 3 decimal places.

Comment: Maybe it says that 12.345 seconds are 12345 milliseconds.

Comment: Doesn't "the time.time()" return the seconds with millisecond precision since the UNIX epoch?

Comment: Not with millisecond precision, it just returns the seconds since epoch. If you want milliseconds, use `int(round(time.time() * 1000))`